# How to select only clients who have their name + something more in second column in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, aggregation

I have table in SQL Teradata like below:

```
client       description
-----------|------------
John Simon |John Simon akrp
Rick Moon  |payment
Ann Terry  |11.05.2019 pay
```

And I would like to find only these **clients which has their name (from column "client") + something more** in column "descpition". So using above example I need to display only John Simon, because he has their name + something more in column description

How can I do that in SQL Teradata?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like`:

```
where description like '%' || client || '%'
```

Comment: Gordon, Is it possible to exclude anything from this list?  for instanse befor or after "client" could be everything but not for instance "aar" or "tty" ?

Comment: @gato . . . This answers the question you asked here:  "And I would like to find only these clients which has their name (from column "client") + something more in column "descpition"."  If you have a different question, please ask as a new question with clear sample data and desired results.